# Joomla - use full article image instead of intro image

Tags: image, joomla, joomla3.0

I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to force Joomla to use full article image if intro image is empty (everywhere where image should be visible).

Is there a setting for this? Is it a feature of a template or Joomla engine itself? Right now I always have to specify both of this images, cause if I specify one only full article image Joomla does not display miniature in many places. If I specify the other one miniature is there but when I enter article it is missing.

I always end up having to specify the same image twice. Is there any way around this?

Thanks

UPDATE1:

I ended up overwriting the template for article to display $images->intro_image whenever $images->image_fulltext is not available.

This solves my problems yet one joomla user tells me she is sure that they were able to do that before without any modifications in the template. So now I'm just wondering if there is a setting for this in Joomla Admin so that it does not have to be forced in template code

Comment: When you say overwrote do you mean you copied the layout and put it into the html folder of your template? I am pretty sure there is no built in option to do this, but it would not be hard to add.

Comment: Yup,it turned out that each element of my page except full article used intro_image. So what I did was to copy out the part responsible for showing article into the html folder of my template and just added a php code to use intro image instead of fulltext image (if it is present).

You basically need to change $image->fulltext to $image->intro_image in the condition. But remember to keep the original condition as an elseif condition if you want to be able to still use full text image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that each element of my page except full article used intro_image. So what I did was to copy out the part responsible for showing article into the html folder of my template and just added a php code to use intro image instead of fulltext image (if it is present). You basically need to change $image->fulltext to $image->intro_image in the condition. But remember to keep the original condition as an elseif condition if you want to be able to still use full text image